# Showing $\bar{S}$ is a convex set if $\forall \bar{x} \in \bar{S}$, $f(x) \geq f(\bar{x})$ where S is closed convex and f is smooth convex

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis, quadratic-programming

I'm really confused on this question. The question states that given the problem $\min_{x \in S} f(x)$, where S is a closed convex set and f a smooth convex function. Let $\bar{S} \subset S$ be the set of points that achieve the global minimum. That is for all $\bar{x} \in \bar{S}$ we have that $f(x) \geq f(\bar{x})$ $\forall x \in S$. Show that $\bar{S}$ is the convex set.

I have no idea how to approach solving this problem. I know from a theorem that:

Let S be a convex set in $\mathbb{R^n}$, f be a continuously differentiable function. Then:

(a) If $\bar{x}$ is a local solution to $\min f(x) \text{ s. t }$ to $x \in S$, then $\bar{x}$ satisfies $\bar{x} \in S$ and $\nabla f(\bar{x})' (x-\bar{x}) \geq 0 \forall x \in S$.

(b) If $\bar{x}$ satisfies (a) and f is convex, then $\bar{x}$ is a global solution of $\min f(x) \text {s. t. } x \in S$.

Here's what I know:

- A set S is convex if for all $x,y \in S$, and $\forall \lambda \in [0,1]$:
  $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in S$

And I'm guessing I have to prove this for $\bar{S}$, but I'm stuck at how to do this. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y\in\bar S$ and $0\le\lambda\le 1$. As $f$ is convex, we have
$$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\le \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y) = \lambda \min f+(1-\lambda)\min f=\min f, $$
but trivially also $$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\ge\min f.$$

(Note that smoothness is not used in this)

Comment: Sorry, this might be a dumb question but how does this show that $\bar{S}$ is a convex set? Just trying to wrap my head around convexity / proof writing a little better.

Answer (score 0):

This is true even for quasi-convex functions!

Let $\alpha$ is minimum value of $f$ over $S$

$\bar{S} =\{x \in S ~ | \quad  f(x) \leq \alpha \} $ which is a level set, so it is convex.